# sporadic DNS resolution issues in Java http client

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, dns

We've got a batch job that runs every day on an EC2 instance within AWS.  The EC2 instance exists in a VPC.  The batch job uses java to make a series of REST API calls on a public server.  Most days the batch job runs without issue.  However, some days, something breaks down in DNS resolution.  The job will be happily running and then suddenly DNS resolution fails and the remaining API calls error out with an exception like the following:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: some.publicserver.com: Name or service not known
  at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
  at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
  at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1277) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:44) ~[batchjob.jar:na]
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:102) ~[batchjob.jar:na]
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:319) ~[batchjob.jar:na]
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363) ~[batchjob.jar:na]
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219) ~[batchjob.jar:na]
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195) ~[batchjob.jar:na]
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86) ~[batchjob.jar:na]
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108) ~[batchjob.jar:na]
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184) ~[batchjob.jar:na]
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) ~[batchjob.jar:na]
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106) ~[batchjob.jar:na]
  ...
```

Some days, every API call will fail with this error, some days there will be a string of successful calls and then everything will start failing.  On the days where the job is failing, I can connect the server at the same time and verify that DNS seems to be working. For example, if I use the following command

```
nslookup some.publicserver.com
```

It returns a successful response. At the same time, the batch job will be spewing a bunch of UnknownHostExceptions.

I am perplexed as to where to look for the source of the problem.  Has anyone out there experienced anything similar to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is not a Java specific problem per say, rather than a DNS resolution issue with the EC2 instance. Java will effectively performs DNS resolving actions firstly by checking the `hosts` file and then by calling the underlying OS's DNS related functions.

With this in mind as well as the fact that the underlying EC2 instance is effectively running a Linux distro, these steps will result in a call to the `gethostbyname2` function of the OS. This in turn will perform all the under the hood magic to resolve the name in question.

Now, two things are very important in troubleshooting your problem. First one is whether the IP address of the server you're calling is changing often. Two is that the `nslookup` program you're using will query the DNS server directly. This means that there could very well be discrepancies between what Java attempts to do to resolve the domain name and what the program does. Furthermore, this may also mean that the OS may have cached up an IP address which does not correspond to the server's latest one. Thus, I would suggest checking the IP address of the hostname using some other utility (e.g. `ping`).

My best advises on troubleshooting this would be the following:

- Adding some kind of log trace when attempting to perform the hostname
  resolution and comparing it with the `nslookup`'s resolved value.
- Checking whether the EC2 has a proper DNS setup (what DNS server
  you're using etc).
- Adding an entry to the `hosts` file mapping the domain name to the IP
  address (provided that the latter one is does not change).

Hope the above help.

Comment: Good suggestions, I hadn't thought maybe the DNS resolution for some.publicserver.com gets stale, which might actually be a problem on their end.  I will add some more logging to the batch job to see if it sheds some light.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, in my particular situation, here's what I have been able to figure out.  Hopefully this will help someone else down the road.

The authoritative DNS servers for the target in my example (some.publicserver.com) are returning SERVFAIL for some requests.  This seems likely to be a load issue as it appears to happen sporadically throughout the day.  With my AWS setup, I am using the default DNS servers for my VPC, which are provided by AWS.  Those servers apparently do not do any caching.  I have learned that Java does some caching for DNS resolutions through InetAddress, but by default it is a short window (30 seconds in most implementations I believe).

So in the end, the real cause of the problem is the authoritative DNS servers for some.publicserver.com not being completely reliable.  Since I have no control over those servers, I think the best workaround is to use DNS caching.  Option #1 is to use local DNS caching on my EC2 Ubuntu instance (something like dnsmasq).  Option #2 is to increase the caching duration used by the Java, by doing something like this:

```
java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl" , "900");
```

I chose option #2 as it required less effort and minimizes the potential side effects.  So for, it has resolved the issue for me.